# Работа с HOOK SetWindowsHookEx и WH_GETMESSAGE

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Здравствуйте!
Просидел сутки читая статьи но так и не разобрался почему не работает... Использую VS 2015 Делаю dll :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::fstream myfile;//создание файла для записи
    myfile.open("C:\\Baza_Ob\\Log.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app); //открытие файла для записи 
    if ( myfile.is_open() )
    {
        char ff = MapVirtualKey(wParam, 2);
        myfile << ff;
        myfile.close();
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}

   И саму программу:

    HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
    MSG msg;// текущий экземпляр
    HOOKPROC hkprc;
    HHOOK hhook;
   // Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:  
  int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
    {       
        hinstDLL = LoadLibrary("hook_dll_2.dll");
        if ( hinstDLL == NULL)
            MessageBox(NULL, "DLL не загружена", "dll", NULL);  
        else MessageBox(NULL, "DLL загружена", "dll", NULL);
        hkprc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "GetMsgProc");
        if (!hkprc )
        MessageBox(NULL, "функция GetMsgProc НЕ!!! найдена", "dll", NULL);      
        else MessageBox(NULL, "функция GetMsgProc подключена", "dll", NULL);    
        hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, hkprc, (HINSTANCE)hinstDLL,0);
        // Цикл основного сообщения:
        Sleep(10000);
        return 0;
    }
```

Сама ДЛЛ подключается а вот функция пишет что не найдена....
срабатывает здесь:

```
if (!hkprc )
            MessageBox(NULL, "функция GetMsgProc НЕ!!! найдена", "dll", NULL);
```

hkprc всегда = 0    Где ошибка?

hkprc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "_GetMsgProc@12");
Результат вас приятно удивит :) Так получилось :)))

Ну, или воспользуйтесь def-файлом при создании hook_dll_2.dll:

LIBRARY hook_dll_2.dll
EXPORTS
GetMsgProc = GetMsgProc          PRIVATE
Так не заработало.... файл создал в студии прописался....

Answer (score 1):

А вы попробуйте запросить

```
hkprc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "_GetMsgProc@12");
```

Результат вас приятно удивит :)

Ну, или воспользуйтесь def-файлом при создании `hook_dll_2.dll`:

```
LIBRARY hook_dll_2.dll
EXPORTS
GetMsgProc = GetMsgProc          PRIVATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в импорте/экспорте функции `GetMsgProc`: `extern "C"` тоже декорирует имена функций. Чтобы этого не происходило, к проекту с `DLL` Вам нужно еще добавить файл `*.def` с таким содержанием:

```
EXPORTS
    GetMsgProc  = GetMsgProc
```

и пересобрать его.

Или можете добавить линкеру опцию, чтобы он генерировал `*.map`-файл. После компиляции `DLL` у Вас в нем будет декорированное имя этой функции. В таком случае, Вам и `extern "C"` уже будет не нужен.

Еще вариант, как определить декорированное имя экспортируемой функции: объявить импорт функции в Вашем `EXE`, например (как будто, вы ее подключаете статически). В таком случае линковщик сообщит об ошибке и укажет имя функции (в том числе и декорированное), которую он не смог импортировать.

Но первый вариант (`*.def`) наиболее грамотный, на мой взгляд. К тому же не требует следить за сменой сигнатуры функции, если у Вас вдруг изменится набор ее параметров или модификаторов.